# How to handle different timezones when using campaigns?

Tags: aem

I have an use case to use campaigns in aem, when after certain range of time period the campaign related carousel slides(which I am pulling from campaigns segments/teasers )has to be disabled and default campaign related slides has to be shown. 
Am having a doubt on how this campaigns are going to be handled when my Aem publish servers has deployed across the timezones?

Also I need to activate new campaigns from author instance  to publish instances ( which has been deployed in across the regions of world) that have to be activated on specific time like (on some public holidays/new year events).

Comment: Why do not use deactivation later functionality?

Comment: @SumantaPakira campaigns are needed to set a time duration for automatic activation and deactivation where the author will not be able to be available for manual action on AEM Servers.

Comment: may be I do not understand your question completely, in AEM author can set the time for deactivation and then AEM will automatically deactivate campaigns, is that not possible for you to do?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but i am having a doubt that if my Author is in USA  time zone and the publish servers are in other time zones like Asia Pacific, Australia, Middle East, etc which will be ahead of time zone. and vice versa. If any campaigns are needed to be published on a specific time like New Year or any occasion. How will be the time zone difference will be handled?

Answer (score 0):

I will follow this approach

1. Store the activation time in a page properties. Lets say prop1.
2. Implements EventHandler and on handleEvent() call a Thread class method (pass the time difference and replication agent id as arguments) to schedule the activation.
3. Implement Thread class in such a way that when time as per step#2 will come then it will execute page Activation for specific Agent ID (Replication Agent ID is unique as it is configured for different publish server in different location).